# How to draw Multi-styled text using Konva?

Tags: konvajs

I am now using KonvaJS.

I know `Text` draws text. But it accepts only one style.

Here's my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmmw7vxkl3) to render text.

And I want to make `Konva` color to `red` and others `green`.

You can do live coding [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/RgBZVK)

Comment: Is it only the color that you need to change, or is it also font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, that is not possible with `Konva`. To resolve your issue you can:

1. Use several instances of `Konva.Text` with different styles
2. Use custom `Konva.Shape` and draw all text manually with native canvas access

Comment: Could you plz share a quick example on that?

Comment: @АленаВерещака but the demo may need some manuall text width calculations for better view.